# How can you use comparisons in switch statements?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to use a comparison (5 > 2) in a switch statement, and I can not get it to work. Can you tell me how to use a comparison in a switch statement?

Here is my if statement:

```
if (5 > 2) {
    console.log("Correct!")
} else if (5 < 2) {
    console.log("Wrong!")
} else {
    console.log("What!?")
}
```

I want to turn the if statement into a switch statement, like this:

```
switch () {
    case :
        break;
    default :
        break;
}
```

If I can't turn my if statement into a switch statement, then please tell me.

Comment: It *can* be done, but it generally *shouldn't* be done because an if/else if/else structure is usually shorter and clearer. (Of course, that's a matter of opinion.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let a = 2, b = 5;
switch(true){
  case a>b:
    console.log('do something here');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('do something there');
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can I change the true to null?

Comment: @Alex - No. The `switch` is trying to match that value to the first `case` with the same value.

Comment: Can I change the true to another date type that has the value of true (for example a string)?

Comment: A string doesn't have the value `true`. So no. Remember, your `case` expressions (if they're things like `x>y`) evaluate to a boolean value.

Comment: That's right, just a boolean value. Anyway it's just an answer for your question, switch(true) is not a good approach.

Comment: Oh, I got confused with other languages because in some languages  a string has the value of true.

Comment: Alex, in JS non-empty strings are "truthy", as are non-zero numbers and all objects, but that's not the same as being equal to boolean `true`. (A proper discussion of "truthy" values is way out of scope for this question, but there are other questions about it.)

Answer (score 0):

There is literally no point to do this – as you can see, to generate acceptable values for the comparison requires essentially duplicate work to be done.

```js
var result;

if (5 > 2) {
    result = 'greater';
} else if (5 < 2) {
    result = 'less';
}

switch(result) {
case 'greater':
    console.log("Correct!")
    break;
case 'less':
    console.log("Wrong!");
    break;
default:
    console.log("What!?");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Or you can do it without duplication, as per the other answer.

Comment: The other answer doesn't handle `b > a` and `b == a` separately.

Comment: Sure it does. The code actually shown in the answer was just a very short example with only one `case` before `default`, but you can add as many cases as you like with separate conditions so you'd just need `case b > a` and `case b == a`.